# How to optimize mysql queries with multiple inequalities?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, query-optimization, database-performance, query-performance

I have hundreds of website queries that look something like this:

```
SELECT blah, blah, blah FROM sometable
WHERE '2015-12-15 18:55:20' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to  
AND date_from > '2015-06-26 10:40:08'  
and ctcx_latitude >= 41.87403474 and ctcx_latitude <= 41.93293328 
and ctcx_longitude >= -87.64343262 and ctcx_longitude <= -87.61356354 
and (LP_LIST_PRICE BETWEEN 90000 and 250000) and BTH_BATHS >= 1.0 and BR_BEDROOMS >= 1
and ASM_ASSESMENT_ASSOCIATION_DUES <= 500 
order by LP_LIST_PRICE
```

Notice how every condition is an inequality.

MYSQL is completely unable to use any index for this query. I've tried many possible combinations, but what it boils down to, is that inequalities don't seem to be properly recognized by the mysql optimizer. This is mysql5.6 on Amazon RDS (latest version supported).

Currently I'm able to work-around this by growing server memory to match table sizes, but this is already 4x more expensive than necessary and will only get worse.

Can this kind of query run well (using indexes efficiently) in mysql?

Comment: Quick question, just to make sure, the conditions are based on user input,  right? It's not going to be the same conditions each time?

Comment: `show create table sometable` show what? explain on query says what?

Comment: Worst case, MySQL 5.6 should be able to choose one good candidate index for a range scan and then further eliminate non-matching rows using the rest of the WHERE clause, but I would also expect it to try index merge.  As @Drew says, we need your table definition and the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Comment: can you restructure data and use spatial indexes? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

> and ASM_ASSESMENT_ASSOCIATION_DUES <= 500

Caution -- if that column can be NULL, this may mess up the `WHERE`.  Suggest you default to `0`, not `NULL`.

You have a tough question, for which there is no good answer.  Some columns (eg, `BTH_BATHS`) are not worth indexing.  Many others may be selective *sometimes*.  If you have single-column indexes on them, the optimizer will try to pick the best among them.  (It will sometimes screw up, since the statistics are rather simple-minded.)

Your example seems to have a rather narrow latitude/longitude bounding box.  If that is the best constraint, and you have a lot of rows, then you might consider the code in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng .

`'2015-12-15 18:55:20' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to` -- Perhaps *most* of the rows are before `date_from`?  And they are cluttering up the table, thereby slowing down your attempts to optimize?  If so, it *might* be worth moving such rows out of the table.